# CMake link issue with relocated libraries

Tags: c, cmake, linker

I have a cascade of libraries  A, B, C with B depending on A and C depending on A and B.

I have a final library D and an executable using it. D depends on A, B and C.

When building and exporting each library at a time to a local repository, everything is fine: D builds, links and the executable works fine.
When manually copying the repository containing A, B, C to another location (and importing to D from that other location), the results are variable:

- Everything works fine on Windows (Visual Studio),
- There's a runtime issue on Cygwin.

The issue is as follows:

- D builds and links,
- When running the executable, it crashes immediately,
- When inspecting D with the "ldd" command, it shows strange things

:

```
??? => ??? (0x53a570000)

??? => ??? (0x180040000)
```

I have tried to make my libraries relocatable but it seems I have missed something...
In the exported target file, there is no absolute path though.

I have seen something about SO_NAME on google so I tried this in D after importing A, B and C:

```
set_property(TARGET A PROPERTY IMPORTED_NO_SONAME 1)
```

but it did not solve the issue.

I'm lost, can somebody please help me ?

EDIT:

The exporting code for A:

```
# Library
add_library(mylibA SHARED
    ${SOURCE_FILES}
    ${PUBLIC_HEADERS}
)
set_target_properties(mylibA PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES mylibA
)
target_include_directories(mylibA
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
target_link_libraries(mylibA)

# Packaging
if(ENABLE_MYLIBA_PACKAGING)
    # Install target to export
    install(TARGETS mylibA
        EXPORT mylibA-export
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "bin"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "bin"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "include/mylibA"
    )
    # Install export
    install(EXPORT mylibA-export
        FILE mylibATargets.cmake
        CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release
        DESTINATION "cmake"
    )
    # Install config file
    install(FILES mylibAConfig.cmake
        CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release
        DESTINATION "cmake"
    )
    export(PACKAGE mylibA)
endif()
```

Import code in D's cmake:

```
# Import
find_package(mylibA PATHS ${REPO_PATH})
find_package(mylibB PATHS ${REPO_PATH})
find_package(mylibC PATHS ${REPO_PATH})

# Library
add_library(mylibD SHARED
  ${SOURCE_FILES}
  ${CONFIG_HEADERS}
  ${PUBLIC_HEADERS}
)
set_target_properties(mylibD PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
)
target_include_directories(mylibD
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${mylibA_INCLUDE_DIR}>
)
target_link_libraries(mylibD
    PUBLIC mylibA
    PUBLIC mylibB
    PUBLIC mylibC
)
```

Comment: Can you show the commands you are using to build the libraries and the executable in both cases, when it works and when not?

Comment: What do you mean with "relocatrable"? Your makefile should have the paths to find the libraries and you must give that to the link command. The requried objects of the libraries are extracted and combined into the executable.

Comment: @Bodo I use cmake to generate cygwin makefiles and simply use the make command to build and make install to export to my repository

Comment: @Darkiwi You should [edit] your question to add clarification. It might be good to show the CMakeLists.txt file(s) and show how your workspace looks like.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie In A, B and C, I set the target properties and avoid setting anything with an absolute path, then I export the target. this exports the binaries, the cmake files (Config and Targets) and the includes.
When importing, i use find_package that locates the Config file and imports all cmake variables.
I link all dynamically so the dlls should be path independent, right?

Comment: @Darkiwi Don't answer in comments, [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: @Bodo Good point, done ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cygwin issue came from access rights: copying the files in Windows was setting "default" very restricted access rights in cygwin, which caused the runtime issue described.

I used a chmod in cygwin after the copy / before the build and link and it solved the issue.